# How to add an anchor to "this.form.submit();"?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Form is submitted by `select_tag`:

```
<%= select_tag :next_status, options_from_collection_for_select(@next_select_list, :id, :name, @next_status_id), { :onchange => "this.form.submit();" } %>
```

How can I add an anchor `#selectbox` to jump to  `<a name="selectbox"> . </a>` near the `select_tag`, when the form is reloaded.

Comment: Not a good idea to submit the form on a select's change event - try navigating the options using the cursor keys in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [slideTo()](http://jesseprice.com/jquery-slide-to-plugin/) plugin like this is one option:

```
$('#selectBox').slideto({
    target : '#test',
    speed  : 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When your form is submitted, the page is re-loaded. So if you want to navigate to an anchor, include it in the URL (i.e. do it at the server).